# Feign REST Client: How to get the HTTP status?

Tags: rest, hystrix, feign

I have Feign client setup with Hystrix and I am trying to log all the HTTP status codes that I get from my API calls into a database. So this means, if one of my calls give me a 201, I would want to log that into DB. If my call results in a failure, my fallback handler can obviously log that but I want to do the DB inserts in one place. Does feign have a way to get access to responses or some kind of general callback?

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide custom `decoder` to get your response in `ResponseEntity<Object>`.

```
NotificationClient notificationClient = Feign.builder()
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                .decoder(customDecoder())
                .target(Target.EmptyTarget.create(NotificationClient.class));
```

Here you define your custom decoder bean. You can define your own by implementing `Decoder` but I'm using spring decoder.

```
@Bean
public Decoder customDecoder() {
    HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(customObjectMapper());
    ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> objectFactory = () -> new HttpMessageConverters(jacksonConverter);
    return new ResponseEntityDecoder(new SpringDecoder(objectFactory));
}
```

Now collect your response in `ResponseEntity<Object>`

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response = notificationClient.notify();
int status = response.getStatusCodeValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create your own `feign.Logger` implementation, overriding the `logAndRebufferResponse` method:

```
protected Response logAndRebufferResponse(
   String configKey, Level logLevel, Response response, long elapsedTime);
```

This may be simpler than creating a `Decoder` and is guaranteed to be called when a response is received regardless of status.  `Decoder`s are only called if the request does not trigger an error.